# Binary numbers (factors ) to the data in R

Tags: r

I am learning R for the first time. not sure how I can assign a "0"  or 1 to the data I have.  I have a list of states and home prices info data frame. how can I assign 0 or 1 to the states?

```
states    HOMEPRICE
 CA          200000  
 AZ         1000000
 SD         230000
 IL         30000
```

For this data ,CA should show as 1 and everything else as 0

```
states    HOMEPRICE    newcolumn 
 CA          200000       1
 AZ         1000000       0
 SD         230000        0
 IL         30000         0
```

appreciate any help

Comment: `df$new_col <- as.integer(df$states == "CA")`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for your reply, sometimes it is possible to have multiple sates at same time. like   df$new_col <- as.integer(df$states == "CA" , "IL")  . that is where the problem i am facing. not sure how to handle  if i have more than one state.

Comment: You did not include that in your question. Please make sure your question is complete and includes what you want to do. For more than one variable you can use `df$new_col <- as.integer(df$states %in% c("CA", "IL"))`